# Override 'git pull' to exit with an echo statement

Tags: git, git-config

I would like to make the changes in my .gitconfig file, so that when i run the "git pull" it exits with the echo statement "please use git xpull instead of git pull" here xpull is my alias?

OR is it possible anywhere in my local machine(instead of .gitconfig file)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Not Possible with Git-Alias

Unfortunately, I don't believe it's possible to do what you want within git itself. The git-config(1) manual page says:

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing git commands are ignored.

In other words, you're free to create a git alias for *xpull*, but you can't actually override or wrap *pull* itself. You can, however, create a shell function to wrap calls to git.

#### Wrap Git with Shell Function

You can wrap git in a shell function that will intercept all calls to git, check for the existence of the keyword "pull," and rewrite the command line to use "xpull" instead. This wrapper function is not particularly robust, but it certainly worked for me in casual testing.

```
git () {
    if [[ "$*" =~ $(echo '\bpull\b') ]]; then
        git xpull
    else
        command git xpull "${@/pull/}"
    fi
 }
```

If you prefer, you could replace the call to *xpull* with an echo and a non-zero return status, but it just seems more sensible to wrap the behavior transparently. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: That is extremely annoying.  Git alias should absolutely allow you to override existing Git commands.

Answer (score 0):

Place a script in `$SOMEDIR/git-pull`, where `$SOMEDIR` is in your `$PATH`, then:

```
chmod -x /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull
```

or wherever the `git-pull` executable is located on your system.

Comment: This admittedly is problematic when your package manager restores the permissions for the original `git-pull` during updates, but the `chmod -x` step is strictly required because `git` actually does not allow to override working built-in commands.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a short alias?  It will save you time for other commands too

```
[alias]
    st = status
    pl = pull --no-edit
```